# Static initializers and safe publication

Tags: java, multithreading

How does initializing an object reference from a static initializer guarantee safe publication?

Comment: Classloading is implicitly synchronized.

Comment: Actually ... it is class initialization that is synchronized.  That may happen "at the same time" as class loading, or it may happen lazily.

Answer (score 3):

Using a static initializer is often the easiest and safest way to publish objects that can be statically constructed:

```
public static Holder holder = new Holder(42);
```

Static initializers are executed by the JVM at class initialization time; because of internal synchronization in the JVM, this mechanism is guaranteed to safely publish any objects initialized in this way [[JLS 12.4.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#44630)].